# Decoding Base64 to pdf Turkish Character Problem

Tags: android, pdf, base64

I am decoding base64 to pdf but Turkish characters(ğ,ş,İ...) doesn't appear when I open pdf.
it should appear like this:
[image: it should appear like this]
but it looks like this now:
[image: it looks like this now].

code snippet is

```
val pathPdf =
    File(
        "${
            Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS
            )
        }/POLSAN${id}.pdf"
    )
val pdfAsBytes: ByteArray =
    Base64.decode("base64string", Base64.DEFAULT)
val fos = FileOutputStream(pathPdf, false)
fos.write(pdfAsBytes)
fos.flush()
fos.close()
```

Comment: You should also post how you're encoding the text, a portion of the text to encode and the encoded resulting text. You can also test using some online tools such as https://www.base64encode.org/ and https://www.base64decode.org/

Comment: Encoded text comes from API. It looks normal (like first pic) when I paste the text to https://base64.guru/converter/decode/pdf

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to use UTF8 to be able to see special characters.

```
String(pdfAsBytes, StandardCharSets.UTF_8)
```